# VBA code to click on Form Dropdown from IE

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, onchange

I am trying to automate some bit of IE, I'm successfully so far but got stuck with clicking on a dropdown from the IE dropdown as it is having a change event.
I was able to click on the dropdown but unable to make the selection from the dropdown.

The code I'm trying to input the value is working but change event is not working.

```
HTML.getElementById("TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY_AUTOCOMPLETE").Value = "DropDownValuetobeselected"
```

The code I'm trying to click on the dropdown is working, but unable to make the selecetion and trigger change event.

```
Set addressInput = HTML.getElementById("TAT_ARROW")
addressInput.Focus
addressInput.Click
```

Below the screenshot of the IE dropdown form

#### IE Dropdown Screenshot

[image: IE Dropdown Screenshot]

Below is the source code:-

```
<TD class=IconArea><A id=TAT_ARROW href="javascript:void(0)" jQuery1480509731310="51"></A></TD>

<SELECT onchange=";processDialog('CMD_REFRESH_DIALOG', 'ETQ$DIALOG_PARENT_TYPE=DOCUMENT&amp;REFRESH_FIELD_NAME=TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY', 'TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY');" onfocus="window.status=unescape('Field name is TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY');" onblur="window.status='';" class=FormField style="DISPLAY: none" size=1 name=TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY optionsLoaded="true"><OPTION class=FormField value=39>DropDownValuetobeselected</OPTION><OPTION class=FormField selected value="">&nbsp;</OPTION></SELECT>
```

Also Posted Here:- [Link](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=201953&p=781673#post781673)

Comment: Have you tried .FireEvent?

Comment: I have tried the below .firevent but no luck. Let me know if I'm missing something.        HTML.getElementById("TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY_AUTOCOMPLETE").Value = "DropDownValuetobeselected"
HTML.getElementById("TAT_Deaprtment_REASSIGN_DIALOG_FACILITY_AUTOCOMPLETE ").FireEvent ("onchange")

Comment: HI, you set the select elements selectedIndex property or value property if you have a string value...  once you have set all of the forms' elements values, you then fire the forms submit event either by sending a click to the default button or firing the forms event handler... preferably you want user action to decide to submit the form with the automated values inserted.